# Facebook JS SDK & PHP SDK without refreshing?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I currently have the facebook js sdk to login to the site and then I want to use the PHP sdk for everything else. How can I pass the accessToken to the PHP SDK to allow me to do this? I want to pass it to a PHP script at a different url, so for example I login at `/login/` and then open up a modal box to `/facebook/?accessToken=gfdhjsfghjkfgdh` or what ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Please check this link.

A sample code may look like this,

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    //got the token
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    //send it to php via _GET
    window.location = "/facebook/?accessToken=" + accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    //but not connected to the app
  } else {
    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

You can get the accesstoken then send it to php.